# Which logistic model should I use in Stata when I have a mix of categorical and scalar variables?

Tags: logistic, stata

I want to run a regression in Stata. The dependent variable is a scalar categorical variable indicating life satisfaction `ls` (1= satisfied, 2= intermediate, 3= dissatisfied).

The independent variables are as follows:

`entrep` = if the person is an entrepreneur (1 if yes, 0 if no)

`edu` = level of education (1 if primary, 2 if high school, 3 if university degree)

`sex` = (1 if male, 0 if female)

`marital` = marital status (1 if single, 2 if married, 3 if divorced, 4 if widowed, 5 if remarried, 6 if cohabiting)

`extro` = scale for personality characteristic of extroversion (range between 0-9, 9 having highest level). This variable is based on several questions and can be a decimal.

`neuro` = scale for personality characteristic of neuroticism (range between 0-10, 10 having highest level). This variable is based on several questions and can be a decimal.

Since I have a mix of categorical and scalar variables, my question is which model should  I use and how exactly can I do it in Stata?

Answer (score 1):

In any statistical software, and not just Stata, the nature of your response variable is what counts here. With a response or dependent variable degree of satisfaction you are dealing with an ordinal response. There are several possible models and ordinal logistic regression is just one.

How to do this in Stata is off-limits here, but can be determined within about a minute by looking at the documentation or using `search`. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more advice on software-related questions.